# Type 'Task' does not satisfy the constraint 'Document'

Tags: mongodb, typescript, mongoose, nestjs

I'm creating API using Nestjs and Mongodb. tasks.service.ts, tried to create a getAll endpoint and got typescript error:
`Type 'Task' does not satisfy the constraint 'Document'. Type 'Task' is missing the following properties from type 'Document': increment, model, $isDeleted, remove, and 51 more.`

tasks.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, HttpStatus } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { Task } from './dto/task.inferface';

@Injectable()
export class TasksService {
  private readonly Tasks: Task[] = [];

  constructor(@InjectModel('Task') private readonly TaskModel: Model<Task>) {}

  async getAll(): Promise<Task> {
    const tasks = await this.TaskModel.find().exec();
    return tasks;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend the document class from the interface.

```js
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

export interface Task extends Document {
 //Task info ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Task shouldn't be a DTO, it should be entity like:

tasks.entity.ts

```
import { Schema, Prop, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

@Schema()
export class Task extends Document {
  @Prop()
  name: string;
}

export const TaskSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Task);
```

2. You also need to register that model in your module:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
      {
        name: Task.name,
        schema: TaskSchema,
      },
    ]),
  ],
})
```

3. So your code will be something like

```
import { Injectable, HttpStatus } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { Task } from './entities/task.entity';

@Injectable()
export class TasksService {
  constructor(@InjectModel(Task.name) private readonly TaskModel: Model<Task>) {}

  async getAll(): Promise<Task> {
    const tasks = await this.TaskModel.find().exec();
    return tasks;
  }
}
```